# Any (Global Illumination) renderers implemented by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rendering

I am wondering if there is any (GI) renderers implemented by Javascript? Furthermore, is it possible to make one on node.js?

Comment: There are some [path tracers based on WebGL](http://madebyevan.com/webgl-path-tracing/). Don't see however how you can benefit from using node.js here.

Comment: Sorry for node.js issue. I just thought it might be benefit from it by making use of server-side js rendering~

Answer (score 0):

Three.js offers few tools for it. It should be working for static scenes as you can see in https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6575.

You can check it at [threejs website](https://threejs.org/).